# Create ASP.NET Syndication Feeds with SqlConnection and VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, rss, syndication

This seems to be a great article by Scott Mitchell for creating syndicated feeds in **ASP.NET 3.5**. The problem for me is that it uses C# and Linq, which I'm not as sharp on at the current time.

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/How-to-create-a-syndication-feed-for-your-website.aspx

Does anyone know where an example might exist for the `System.ServiceModel.Syndication` namespace that can produce a syndicated feed like this article using **VB.NET** and a **SQLConnection** object?

I've looked around and every example seems to be produced in C# and Linq (which is probably a testament to my need to learn them soon rather than later).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You’ve probably figured it out by now, but here’s an implementation for completeness and some VB love (and an attempt for the [Necromancer badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/17/necromancer). :)

The aspx page is simple, note the 60 second cache:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="YourProject._Default" %>
<%@ OutputCache Duration="60" VaryByParam="Type" %>
```

You probably want to consider using an HttpHandler instead, but this will work just fine too.

The code behind:

```
Imports System.ServiceModel.Syndication
Imports System.Xml

Partial Public Class _Default
  Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim dbConn As String = "[your db connection]"
    Dim format As FeedFormats = GetFeedFormat()
    Dim posts As New List(Of SyndicationItem)

    Using cnn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(dbConn)
      cnn.Open()

      Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT ID, Title, Text, Url, Created FROM Posts", cnn)
        Dim reader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

        While reader.Read
          Dim item As New SyndicationItem(reader.Item("Title"), reader("Text"), New Uri(reader("Url")))

          posts.Add(item)
        End While
      End Using
    End Using

    Dim feed As New SyndicationFeed("Your feed title", "Your feed description", New Uri("http://yourdomain.com"), posts)

    Using feedWriter As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(Response.OutputStream)
      Select Case format
        Case FeedFormats.Atom
          Response.ContentType = "application/rss+xml"

          Dim atomFormatter As New Atom10FeedFormatter(feed)
          atomFormatter.WriteTo(feedWriter)
        Case FeedFormats.Rss
          Response.ContentType = "application/atom+xml"

          Dim rssFormatter As New Rss20FeedFormatter(feed)
          rssFormatter.WriteTo(feedWriter)
      End Select
    End Using
  End Sub

  Private Function GetFeedFormat() As FeedFormats
    If Request.QueryString("format") = "atom" Then
      Return FeedFormats.Atom
    Else
      Return FeedFormats.Rss
    End If
  End Function

  Public Enum FeedFormats
    Rss = 1
    Atom = 2
  End Enum
End Class
```

Finally, for super-completeness, the SQL script for creating the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Posts](
 [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [Title] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [Text] [ntext] NOT NULL,
 [Url] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [Created] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Posts] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Posts] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Posts_Url]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [Url]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Posts] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Posts_Created]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [Created]
GO
```

Done. VB.NET, a SQL Connection, the `System.ServiceModel.Syndication` namespace, and no LINQ. :)

Update: Got the Necromancer badge on 11-11-2010. Yay! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an example using those objects in  VB.Net, but there are several ways to transform c# code to VB.Net.  You could use an IDE like SharpDevelop, you could use any of several free online converters.

My favorite technique would be to download or cut and paste the source into visual studio and compile the project in C#.  Then use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to disassemble the IL to VB.Net. By doing that you can compare the C# to VB.Net and it may help you see the similarities and pick up C# faster if that is what you would like to do.

Comment: Actually, I did get that far by finding a translator. It's the Linq code I am not having a good time translating, now.

Comment: Have you tried Microsoft's Visual LINQ Query Builder add-in? http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vlinq It's a nice tool similar to the old Access Query Builder.

Comment: Well, frankly, I don't want to use LINQ for this project. I am trying to stick with the SQL Data Layer for now, at least.