# Rss Service programmatically

Tags: asp.net

How can I use RSS service In my web site programmatically ?

Comment: needs more information, what is the RSS Service to do? what is using it? a windows app? a web app? do you want to aggregate content using RSS to display on pages of the site?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880954/create-asp-net-syndication-feeds-with-sqlconnection-and-vb-net/2153032#2153032

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RSS.NET -An open-source .NET class library for RSS feeds 
http://www.rssdotnet.com/